# sql trigger after insert,update same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2019

My data is imported through the external system into the SQL Server.
I want to write a trigger that allows all data to be added to the database by default unless they have special conditions to be updated (they must be updated).

I mean, we should search on all input records and if we have some duplicate data (based on the above conditions), the insert operation should not be performed and only the new input data should replace the old data (Update Action).

Could you please help me?

Comment: If you want to abort an insert, you must use a before insert trigger, not after insert. Could you please show what you have tried so far and what exactly you still need to know? How to create a trigger can be googled.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983) Give us something *specific* to help you with. What have you tried? Why isn't it working?

Comment: Have you tried a MERGE statement? This would take care of new and existing rows in the target table by Inserts or updates. Is the input data placed into a staging table in the DB? If so is it purged at any stage, or at least the rows that have been processed marked as such?

Comment: Sounds like you want a `MERGE`. Messing about with `BEFORE` triggers is the wrong approach

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_YourTable ON dbo.YourTable
FOR INSERT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DELETE tbl
FROM dbo.YourTable AS tbl
JOIN inserted ON inserted.ID = tbl.ID
WHERE inserted.ID in (select ID from dbo.YourTable);
GO
```